# Which package provides Tcl's fileutil::magic::mimetype?

Tags: tcl

I'm attempting to run a Tcl program, [Sguil](https://github.com/bammv/sguil) server, on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

After modifying the configuration files as per the instructions I ran the program:

```
sudo ./sguild
```

I received the following error:

```
2020-05-10 15:13:29 Error: Failed to load package fileutil::magic::mimetype. fileutil::magic::mimetype is required for HTTPS/WSS.
```

I confirmed that `fileutil` is available:

```
echo "puts [package req fileutil]" | tclsh
1.16
```

And that `fileutil::magic::mimetype` is not available:

```
echo "puts [package req fileutil::magic::mimetype]" | tclsh
can't find package fileutil::magic::mimetype
```

I ran the following, which suggests that `fileutil` is included in `tcllib`:

```
dpkg -S tcl | grep fileutil
tcllib: /usr/share/doc/tcllib/html/fileutil.html
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil/pkgIndex.tcl
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil/multi.tcl
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil/traverse.tcl
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil/fileutil.tcl
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil/multiop.tcl
tcllib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19/fileutil/decode.tcl
tcllib: /usr/share/man/man3/fileutil.3tcl.gz
```

The `tcllib` package is already installed:

```
apt list tcllib
Listing... Done
tcllib/bionic,bionic,now 1.19-dfsg-2 all [installed]
```

Any ideas why `fileutil::magic::mimetype` fails to load, or what package provides it?

Comment: It looks like [This command has been removed and its features incorporated into fileutil::magic::filetype.](http://blog.tcl.tk/17368)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, that was it! I assume the program was expecting an older version of Tcl and the Tcl libraries to be installed. I updated the source code to refer to `fileutil::magic::filetype` instead and it worked.

Comment: Please consider writing that as an answer - it may help others who have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @steeldriver pointed out, the `fileutil::magic::mimetype` library is no longer a part of the Tcl libraries, but its features are now available in `fileutil::magic::filetype`. This library available in the `tcllib` package.

(This appears to be a change in Tcl 8.6, the version available in the bionic repos for Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I checked a CentOS 7 machine with Tcl 8.5 and the `fileutil::magic::mimetype` library was present.)

In my case I was able to resolve the errors by updating references in the code for the Sguil application from `fileutil::magic::mimetype` to `fileutil::magic::filetype`.